# Dynamic search with pagination in MVC

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, pagination

my problem is to implement dynamic search in my MVC project. So far I'have only implemented the pagination. I want the search to return all the results found in the database that meet the input and not only the results on the current page. For this I have red that I need to use Angular JS and did a research and a few tries but none worked. 
P.S. Since the search will be on my index page I think its a good idea to make the Index ActionResult cached in order not to call this method every time i input a symbol in the searchbox? What is your opinion.

How to create the dynamic search and sorting on the columns ?
Here is my code:

Controller

```
 public class TeachersController : Controller
    {
        private RSEntities db = new RSEntities();

        // GET: Teachers
        // Use cache only if implemented dynamic search, otherwise not needed
        //[OutputCache(Duration =110, Location=System.Web.UI.OutputCacheLocation.Any, NoStore = true)]
        public ActionResult Index(int page = 1, int pageSize = 8)
        {
            List<tblTeacher> listTeachers = db.tblTeachers.ToList();
            PagedList<tblTeacher> model = new PagedList<tblTeacher>(listTeachers, page, pageSize);
            //return View(db.tblTeachers.ToList()); 
            return View(model);
        }
}
```

Here is the HTML view

```
@*@model IEnumerable<Rating_System.Models.tblTeacher>*@
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@model PagedList.IPagedList<Rating_System.Models.tblTeacher>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Списък с преподаватели";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Преподаватели</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Добавяне на запис", "Create")
</p>


<label>Quick Search: <input id="search" type="text"></label>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().FirstName)

        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().SecondName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().PersonalCabinet)
        </th>

        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().TelNum)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().Email)
        </th> 
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.First().TDepartment)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FirstName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SecondName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PersonalCabinet)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TelNum)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TDepartment)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Редактирай", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Детайли", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Изтрий", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
<br />
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page, pageSize = Model.PageSize }))
Резултати @Model.FirstItemOnPage - @Model.LastItemOnPage от общо @Model.TotalItemCount преподаватели
```

Comment: you want to use Jquery Datatable? searching and sorting is easy to maintain in jquery datatable.

Comment: https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

Comment: I need help with the code, especially the angular js and how to connect it with the action result

Comment: You do not _need to use Angular JS_ Refer [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to get you started.

Comment: thanks, i was just watching the same thing but I kinda wanted to have dynamic search box. Guess I will do it the old fashion way with "Search" button